# How to set a timer & clear a timer?

Tags: python, timer

I want to create a timer. When it times out, some actions will be taken. But, I can interrupt this timer and reset it.
The pseudo code looks like below:

```
def timeout():
    print "time out!"
    T.cancel()  # reset timer T
    T = Timer(60, timeout)  
    T.start()

T = Timer(60, timeout)

def interrupt():
    T.cancel()  # reset timer T
    T = Timer(60, timeout)
    T.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    T.start()
    while True:
        if something is True:
            # interrupt
```

The solution I came up with is cancel the timer in function interrupt and then create a new timer. But it seems a timer is canceled and a new timer is created, which is not high performance.
Any idea?

Comment: can you post your real code instead of your pseudo code, demonstrating how the thread "vanishes"?

Comment: sorry, I made mistake. because timer is related with thread, I mess them up. Have corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [threading.Timer()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#timer-objects) class is likely what you're looking for:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep
from random import random
from threading import Timer

def timeout():
    print("Alarm!")

t = Timer(10.0, timeout)
t.start()              # After 10 seconds, "Alarm!" will be printed

sleep(5.0)
if random() < 0.5:     # But half of the time
     t.cancel()        # We might just cancel the timer
     print('Canceling')
```

Comment: my problem is I do not know how to reuse the timer. If every time the interruption occurs, cancel old timer and then create new timer,which is not of high performance.

Comment: What makes you think canceling a timer and making a new one would perform any differently from suspending and resuming a timer? The pure python overhead and the operating system calls would be substantially similar (and just as insignificant compared to the rest of your program).

Comment: How would you suspend and resume the timer? That's the question he's asking. And yes, spawning new threads is expensive.